# Testing Multiplayer Game Center game

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator, game-center

I've read varying/conflicting answers, and I need some definite answers.

I'm currently at the start of developing a turn-based multiplayer game with `Game Center`. I've been following a [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5509/beginning-turn-based-gaming-with-ios-5-part-2) @[rayWenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials), and I've got the player being authenticated in the simulator and the match making viewController popping up, but that's as far as I've got.

So first question is,

1. Is it possible for my code (via the simulator), and my iPhone to
   connect/match/find each other?

   - I've read that this is not possible, but I'm sure I saw a Youtube video of a guy that got both of them communicating
2. What aspects of turn-based Game Center functionality can you test with just the simulator and 1 device?

---

**Update:**

I wasn't imagining things, after a bit of searching, [I found that Youtube video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqGORADIaEs)

Maybe it's something different, but it seems to be possible to match/play from the simulator to an `iOSDevice` and back again. How is that compared to what people say you can't do on here?

Comment: The video is not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have recently made a turn based application for iPhone and i used my iPhone and the simulator on my computer to test it out and it work just fine. There are one thing you should keep in mind and that is that you have to use different accounts for GC on your iPhone and the simulator.

I am not quite sure what you mean with question two but you can use all the hardware functions that the simulator offers even when you are playing online. keep in mind that you can't test the multiplayer part of your program on just the simulator, it has to be between at least tested with one device and the simulator.

Comment: Hi,  plz check below link,    https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/TestingYourGameCenter-AwareGame/TestingYourGameCenter-AwareGame.html       
Testing Your Game in iOS Simulator
Leaderboards and achievements work the same way in iOS Simulator as they do on a device. However, matchmaking invitations may not be sent or received while your game is running in iOS Simulator.     so, how it works for you?.. am little confused.

Answer (score 5):

The only difference between testing on simulator and physical device is `GKTurnBasedEventHandler` doesn't work on the simulator. So these methods won't be called on iOS Simulator :

```
-(void)handleInviteFromGameCenter:(NSArray *)playersToInvite
-(void)handleMatchEnded:(GKTurnBasedMatch *)match
-(void) handleTurnEventForMatch:(GKTurnBasedMatch *)match didBecomeActive: (BOOL)didBecomeActive
```

While using an `iOS Simulator` and a `Device` for testing, those methods will be called on device but not in simulator. So it will very hard to develop.

Comment: Any ideas why that's the case?

Comment: it's all about architecture of the processors. So there is nothing we can do.

Comment: But I've an advice for you. You can test your game on iOS simulator with clicking on home button. Yo have to refresh the UI when user presses on home button and on app icon back. So you can test those methods that I've listed on device and test your viewDidLoad , viewDidAppear etc. method on simulator. It will be like your simulator handles the turn every time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can match games between the simulator and the device, I have been able to do it before, just keep in mind that you have to use two different Apple/GameCenter accounts.

As per the turn-based aspects, what are you looking for, as far as I've seen, on the simulator you can test anything you can on the device in terms of Game Center, so I guess it will depend on your backend.

Comment: Plz check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266089/gkmatchrequest-invitation-not-showing-in-other-device, I dont understand why I am not getting the notification in the otehr device. Could be the issu related with handleInviteFromGameCenter or GKTurnBasedEventHandlerDelegate??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simulator if you are using "Auto Match".  However, in my limited experience, there are some bugs that can present themselves on actual devices that you couldn't see before.  For instance, if you have poorly written code that ends up depending on the processing speed of the device in order to execute correctly.